# Unable to set array in NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, ios8.1, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

This is my Obj-C code:

```
    NSMutableArray *staffNamesArray = [[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] arrayForKey:@"staffNamesArray"] mutableCopy];

    NSInteger indexSelected = [oStaffPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [staffNamesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexSelected withObject:textField.text];

    [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] setArray: staffNamesArray forKey:@"staffNamesArray"];  //  save it to the cloud
    [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
```

IndexSelected is 0; textfield.text = @"Kellie".

For some reason, staffNamesArray never gets set.  Why?

Comment: If the array doesn't already exist in the store, then `staffNamesArray` will be `nil`. Check for that.

Comment: Hi Rick... that was it... I initialized the array, but forgot to save it to the store... fixed it and it works like a champ.  Thank you again... If you rewrite your comment as an answer, I can close this and give you points. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely issue is this line:

```
NSMutableArray *staffNamesArray = [[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] arrayForKey:@"staffNamesArray"] mutableCopy];
```

This will result in `staffNamesArray` being `nil` if there is no data. You need to check for this and create an array as needed:

```
NSMutableArray *staffNamesArray = [[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] arrayForKey:@"staffNamesArray"] mutableCopy];
if (!staffNamesArray) {
    staffNamesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}

// and the rest of your code
```